# How can I make a webshim date picker uneditable by the user?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I am using the template webshim from-to datepicker laid out here:

http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/KEfEX/embedded/result,html,js,css/

html:

```
    <form action="#" class="ws-validate">
    <div class="form-row">
        <!-- max of the first date equals value of the second --> <!-- mmin of the second date equals value of the first -->
        <input data-dependent-validation='{"from": "date-to", "prop": "max"}' type="date" id="date-from" placeholder="from" />
        <input data-dependent-validation='{"from": "date-from", "prop": "min"}' type="date" id="date-to" placeholder="to" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <input type="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
<p>
    <a href="http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/demos/cfgs/input-date.html" target="_blank">date configurator</a>
</p>
```

javascript:

```
webshim.setOptions('forms', {
    lazyCustomMessages: true,
    addValidators: true
});
webshim.setOptions('forms-ext', {
    replaceUI: 'auto',
    types: 'date',
    date: {
        startView: 2,
        size: 2,
        classes: 'hide-spinbtns'
    }
});

//start polyfilling
webshim.polyfill('forms forms-ext');

//initial max/min attributes should be done serverside.
$(function(){
    $('#date-from, #date-to').prop('min', function(){
        return new Date().toJSON().split('T')[0];
    });
});
```

I've made a couple structural changes to how it is maintained, but all in all it's pretty similar to the example.  My issue with this implementation is that the user is able to manually edit the information in the datepicker text box (which you can see if you click the link).  The implementation does a great job if the user selects both dates from the boxes of preventing erroneous inputs, but if the user decides to enter their own numbers, they can enter whatever they want and the form does no error checking.  The only input that the form prevents the user from entering manually is if the end date is earlier than the start date, and even here the dates have to be properly formatted for it to do error checking.  The ideal and simplest fix would be to make the textbox uneditable by the user.  I've tried

```
contenteditable="false"
```

but it seems to have no effect on the datepicker.  I'm quite new to javascript and html, so I'm not sure all the ins and outs yet, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using asp.net MVC if that has any relevance to the question at hand.

Comment: <input type="{whatever}" readonly/> http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp

Comment: @Baruch This disables the datepicker itself as well unfortunately :(.  I want the user to be able to select a date, just not enter their own.

Comment: hmm, i've been trying to use jquery keypress to prevent default (which is writing) but that doesn't seem to work either. i think you need to find a way to make it so it can error check if it is edited by the user manually

Comment: @Baruch That's what I was afraid of >_<.  So much extra work haha!